# concurrent access to MySQL database using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have a stored procedure that will read and then increment a value in the database. This particular procedure is used by many programs at the same time. I am concerned about the concurrency issues, in particular the reader-writer problem. Can anybody please suggest me any possible solutions?

thanks.

Comment: You should probably use transactions in the stored procedure... maybe I'm old fashioned and there are some more modern approaches, but I use transactions to achieve this - I use transactions for every operation that can't be written as a single query.

Comment: but transactions don't prevent from another application reading the value...I mean if process A is using the stored procedure[using transaction] to update the column1 of row1, then process B can still read the column1 of row1, but it will get the existing value not the updated value. Hope you understand what I mean. If I am wrong, can you please explain?

Comment: Using transactions you won't deny the process B to do his job and that's not at all the purpose of the transaction. The purpose of the transaction is to always get a consistent state, *as if the process were the only one using the database at the same time*. So the process B can read the old state of the db when process A is in the middle of the transaction. And every transaction will pass as if noone else was using the database at the same time.

Comment: correct and thats my problem....transaction wont stop the other processes accessing the same value....it will just make sure that read and write operation won't happen at the same time without denying the access....but I need to LOCK the row once I start to update it. But as far as I know, LOCK is not allowed in a stored procedure....please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Some good reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html http://mtocker.livejournal.com/52721.html

Answer (score 21):

First, as stated in another post, use InnoDB.  It is the default storage engine as of MySQL 5.5 and is more robust.

Second, look at this page:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

You should use a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE to prevent other connections from reading the row you are about to update until your transaction is complete:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT value INTO @value
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 5
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE mytable
SET value = value + 1
WHERE id = 5;

COMMIT;
```

This is better than locking the table because InnoDB does row level locks.  The transaction above would only lock the rows where id = 5... so another query working with id = 10 wouldn't be held up by this query.

Answer (score 2):

if possible you can lock the table just before calling the SP then unlock immediately after.
i had i similar problem and this is how i circumvented this issue.

example

```
LOCK TABLES my_table LOW_PRIORITY WRITE;
CALL my_stored_procedure('ff');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: What happens in case of any other procedure tries to use the table that is locked? Will it wait till the lock is released or will it result in an exception?

Comment: @Akshay it will wait for the table to be unlocked

Answer (score 0):

Use Innodb.
Inside the stored procedure start transaction before do anything else. At the Commit and end the transaction. This will resolve the read/write problem.

But be aware of the fact that it will slow down concurrent operation. It is fine for the case only  a few concurrent request are expected at a given time.

Comment: can you please explain how transaction would resolve my issue....please read my comment on 'Tomas T.' response above.

Comment: OK.
You have to use LOCK TABLE for this case. i.e. you have to explicitly lock the table from being read. And release lock after your work is done.
But it has its own pitfalls
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: yeah, but I can't use LOCK in a stored procedure, can I?

Comment: ok, you are right. can you please post the stored procedure code. I'll think if there is any alternative.

Comment: You can lock table in php code before you call procedure.
After procedure is just finished unlock table.

i.e. mysql_query("LOCK TABLES tablename READ;");
mysqli_query("call stored procedure");
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");

Comment: I haven't tried it. But may be it will lead you towards the solution. I saw you in mysql chat also. you are searching for it everywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table (or reuse the original if appropriate) for all of the incremental inserts and use a SUM() for retrieval.

If there's still a concern about the number of eventual rows, then use a transaction to sum them into a single row back in the original table periodically.  Most likely the trade-off of eventual consistency in the sum (reads lagging the writes) or performance hit in summing rows is less of an issue when compared to the stalls on multiple writers waiting on a lock to a single row.