# Can you lock tables inside MySQL stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I do all database operations using stored procedures and I am concerned with concurrency issues. I see people advise using transactions but to my knowledge, transactions have nothing to do with concurrency controls. I need a way to lock access to tables just like locks in Java I am familiar with. Something I can control concurrent access. I can't seem to use LOCK TABLES statement inside stored procedures. So how does one go about locking tables inside stored procedures?

Comment: "_but to my knowledge, transactions have nothing to do with concurrency controls_" - your knowledge is in need of improvement then. I would suggest, before proceeding any further with database admin, you read a lot more about how ACID compliant database engines work.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520718/concurrent-access-to-mysql-database-using-stored-procedure

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I do know that concurrency controls are done when the same transaction is called simultaneously but that's not what I am asking for. If you read my question carefully I do state that my concerns are with locking at the table level.

Comment: @Hermanto, I read that post and people are advising to use transactions there again which does not solve my problems. One solution that makes sense to me from that post is locking from the higher level code (ex. php) above the database, this I had in mind as my last resort. I was just wondering if an experienced dba might tell me if it is possible to lock individual tables inside stored procedures manually just like the LOCK TABLES statement.

Comment: Calling `LOCK TABLES` in MySQL [commits the current transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html). The very fact that you are asking about `LOCK TABLES` tells me you need to read more. MySQL's Innodb engine supports [row level locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html), which is carried out automatically when `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is called on a number of rows (which is explained in the dup). Basically what I am trying to say is that your question shows a distinct lack of understanding and cannot really be answered as it stands.

Comment: ahhh ok. Looking at the document you provided I understand what you are saying now. Thanks for pointing me to them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, so my understanding is that by using transactions, even if two independent transactions run simultaneously and modify at same time, this would be safe because the database engine is smart enough to rerun the whole transaction again if race condition is about to happen. Am I understanding this correctly?